# What resource is most needed to speed up a complex conda install

Tags: conda

I'm installing a significant number of conda packages [it happens to be in a jupyter environment].

Conda, by it's nature, takes a long while to figure out the best combination of releases for all the packages. It is *significantly* faster on my workstation than it is in my CI build system... and I really, **really** need to speed this process up.

I don't want to switch to `pip` as that can leave me with incompatible library versions.

The question is what compute resource is going to make the most difference: CPU clock speed; number of compute cores; or RAM?

**EDIT**
Following a comment, here's an example

```
FROM jupyter/tensorflow-notebook:dd2087c75645
# dc9744740e12
LABEL MAINTAINER="NaaS Project <edina@ed.ac.uk>"

USER root

# We need libsodium23
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    less \
    libgl1 \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    sharutils \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER $NB_USER

# python3 updates and additional files
RUN conda install --quiet --yes \
    'beautifulsoup4' \
    'bokeh==2.0.1' \
    'cloudpickle' \
    'conda-build' \
    'cython' \
    'dask' \
    'graphviz' \
    'ffmpeg' \
    'imagemagick' \
    'ipympl==0.5.6' \
    'ipywidgets' \
    'jupyterhub' \
    'libxml2' \
    'lxml'  \
    'matplotlib==3.2.2' \
    'matplotlib-base==3.2.2' \
    'mpld3' \
    'nltk' \
    'notebook' \
    'numba' \
    'numexpr' \
    'numpy' \
    'opencv' \
    'pandas' \
    'patsy' \
    'plotly' \
    'protobuf' \
    'psutil' \
    'pytables' \
    'python-graphviz' \
    'rise' \
    'scikit-image' \
    'scikit-learn' \
    'scipy' \
    'seaborn' \
    'spacy' \
    'spectral' \
    'sqlalchemy' \
    'statsmodels' \
    'sympy' \
    'textblob' \
    'unixodbc' \
    'vega' \
    'vincent' \
    'widgetsnbextension' \
    'wordcloud' \
    'xlrd' \
    'xmlschema' \
  && conda build purge-all
```

This takes 15+ minutes to complete

Comment: I don't know the answer regarding hardware, but you can try out [`mamba`](https://github.com/TheSnakePit/mamba), which advertises itself as a drop-in replacement for conda. It is much faster than conda.

Comment: How many packages are we talking? Do you have the list? How are you creating the environment?

Comment: @AMC - Question updated to add install list

Comment: @CodeGorilla Could you narrow down the versions for some of the packages? Which version of Python are you using, for example?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to improve the speed of your `conda install` command is to tweak the command or try a different solver (see below).  But since your question was phrased narrowly about CPU hardware, I'll answer that first.

### Hardware considerations

Anaconda published a [relevant blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/how-we-made-conda-faster-4-7) about the performance bottlenecks in conda, and it listed the following steps that can be parallelized:

> - Downloading and reading repodata from multiple channels
> - Verifying transactions
> - Executing transactions

To benefit from that parallelism, though, you should configure your `.condarc` file to actually use multiple threads for those steps, as described [here in the conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#configuring-number-of-threads).

For example:

```
conda config --set default_threads 4
```

But you asked about the solving time in particular.  Since that isn't listed above, it is not parallelized.  For that, only a faster CPU will improve performance, unless you improve the command you're running as described below.

---

### Alternatives to better hardware

These options are more likely to improve the install time than upgrading your hardware.

#### 1. Be more specific

Anaconda has a [blog post explaining how to help the solver work faster](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance).  They offer a few suggestions, but in your case the most relevant one is to be more specific about the package versions you need.  For example, if you know. you need `dask>=2`, then add `"dask>=2"` to your command.  If you know you need `pandas` 1.x, then specify `pandas=1` in your command.  Every time you add requirements to your package specifications, you reduce the set of possible packages the solver needs to look at in order to find a consistent package set for your environment.

#### 2. Try mamba

If it's really the solving step (not the verify or execute steps) that is the bottleneck for you, you can try an alternative solver.  [mamba](https://github.com/TheSnakePit/mamba) can be installed alongside `conda`, and it can provide faster solves for big environments.

```
conda install mamba -c conda-forge
mamba install --quiet --yes \
    'beautifulsoup4' \
    # etc...
```

Beware: If there is more than one "solution" to the package requirements you listed, then the solver has to choose which one is "best" given the under-specified requirements.  In those cases, `conda` and `mamba` do not always make the same choices.  Presumably, the differences don't matter -- otherwise you would have specified more precise requirements.  But you should be aware that there can be a difference in behavior between the two.  Technically, `mamba` is not *quite* a drop-in replacement for `conda` in all cases.